# How Hibernate exactly monitor object after calling get() or load() method during the session

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection

i know when we invoke get or load method, hibernate create an object using reflection calling up default constructor. but i am not able to understand how hibernate monitor that object during the session.

suppose i have an POJO class representing Entity in database.

```
public class User {
    private int userId;
    private String userName
    // getters and setters.
}
```

suppose in DB.
a record present

userId   -- 1

userName -- john

```
    Session session = sessionfactory.openSession(); // Line 1
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();    //Line 2

    User user = (User) session.load(User.class,1); //Line 3
    user.getUserName(); //Line 4

    tx.commit(); //Line 5
    session.close(); //Line 6
```

but at console select query happen at line 4 when we call getUserName() not at line 3.yes i know using load we get only proxy object fine. but at line 4 we only call POJO getter but how it hit the database select query in a simple java manner it is not understandable. is there any kind of reflection. can any body explain me how it's exactly working.

Again if i get object using get() method.

```
    Session session = sessionfactory.openSession(); // Line 1
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();    //Line 2
    User user = (User) session.get(User.class,1); //Line 3
    user.setUserName("mark"); //Line 4
    tx.commit(); //Line 5
    session.close(); //Line 6
```

select query happen at line 3. ok fine get() hit the DB.but again at line 4 we only call setter but how it hit the database update query at end of transaction at line 5.

i go through source but not understand.
in my thinking it's look like reflection and event handling kind of thing.object or proxy object created
by get() or load() using reflection and then monitoring the object state change like event handling.is there observer design pattern or something else.

if i am thinking in right direction so can some one please give me example or link for practice because i have less knowledge about reflection. i also want to do similar kind of thing monitoring object state.

Answer (score 0):

**One of the key difference between get() and load() method**

`load()` method  will check the entity in  session level cache first. If it found, then the entity will be returned from cache else it will query the database and return it to the client. But the `get()` method will directly fetch from database.

My assumption (**Kindly correct me if I’m wrong**):

```
User user = (User) session.load(User.class,1); //Line 3
user.getUserName(); //Line 4
```

Line 3 says you need a particular object fine. But it’s not guaranteed that you will use it.so they might have implemented lazy fetch sort of stuff for memory management. If you are not using it then you are wasting one instance. But in big picture this might be a rational design.

```
User user = (User) session.load(User.class,1); //Line 3

//do some other operations…
```

But when it comes to `get()` method the case is different. It fetches directly from database every time. In this case it supposed to load the data first (no second thought here) because it cannot hold some pointer stuff till you load the data when you call getter method (it might fall into connected architecture). Basically that is expensive as I personally believe.

Hibernate observes object state based on the object value not by the object reference. But in case of collections, hibernate use identity.

Comment: Thank's for replying.i know the difference between load and get, but my question is how hibernate session observe that object and when object state change,then hibernate perform some task.